# What is exactly dangling-else problem in c?

Tags: c, dangling-else

How can the code work like this?
Which if-else statements are linked with each other?
So why is the output like that "$$$$$"?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int x = 11;
    int y = 9;

    if(x<10)
    if(y>10)
    puts("*****");
    else
    puts("#####");
    puts("$$$$$");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ­­­­­-­­­­­1 Why not just use the curly brackets and avoid the confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save time.  Use an auto formatter.

Hopefully then "why is the output like that "$$$$$"?" is self apparent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int x = 11;
  int y = 9;

  if (x < 10)
    if (y > 10)
      puts("*****");
    else
      puts("#####");
  puts("$$$$$");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or use braces to properly display scopes

Comment: Okay but I want to understand how it works and why is the output "$$$$$"?

Comment: Since `x` is superior to 10 you never enter in the `if` so you jump to the next line of the current scope in this case `puts("$$$$$");`

Comment: @Atakan The `$$$$$` is unconditional.

Comment: @Atakan The first `if (x < 10)` is false so `if (y > 10)
      puts("*****");
    else
      puts("#####");` is not executed.

Comment: @Atakan In the absence of braces, the `else` goes with the nearest preceding `if`. So the code checks `x < 10`, and then skips to the `puts("$$$$$")` because `x` is not less than 10.